# In Kotlin, how can I instantiate a generic class using a native java parameter?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am exploring using BDB JE (Berkeley DB Java Edition) with Kotlin. Knowledge of BDB is not necessary to answer this question.

BDB has a method that looks like this:

```
store.getPrimaryIndex(Int::class.java, "Int", Person::class.java, "Person")
```

I want to do things generically, so I wrote this

```
inline fun <reified TModel : Any, reified TKey : Any> getIndex() = 
    return store.getPrimaryIndex(TKey::class.java, TKey::class.simpleName, TModel::class.java, Model::class.simpleName)
```

So far so good. I now want to pass this index object to a class, which looks like this:

```
class ModelStore<TModel, TKey>(index : PrimaryIndex<TKey, TModel>) {
    private val index = index

    fun get(key : TKey): TModel = index.get(key)
    fun put(model : TModel) = index.put(model)
}
```

But if I try and pass the output from `getIndex<User, Int>()` to `ModelStore<User, Int>` I get the following error:

> Type inference failed: Expected type mismatch: Inferred type is
>   `PrimaryIndex<TModel!, TKey!>!` but `PrimaryIndex<TModel, TKey>` was
>   expected.

My question: Can I pass the the index to the `ModelStore`? How do I convince the type-system that this is kosher?

Comment: What is the return type of `getIndex`?

Comment: @hotkey: PrimaryIndex<TModel!, TKey!>!

Comment: This also reproduces the error: `val users : PrimaryIndex<Int, User> = store.getPrimaryIndex(Int::class.java, "Int", User::class.java, "User")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest workaround is to cast the types:

```
ModelStore<User, Int>(getIndex<User, Int>() as PrimaryIndex<User, Int>)
```

Also I would expect it to work without specifying the types:

```
ModelStore(getIndex<User, Int>())
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of these approaches work - I hadn't realized you could just leave the type arguments off of class constructors. I am too used to C#, where function type parameters can be derived, but not class parameters. In any case, I have gone for explicitly casting, as I'd rather not have the platform types propagating.